# MYSQL: Returning multiple counts from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to return multiple counts from multiple tables. Here is what I have to return multiple counts from the same table (much thanks to help from here):

```
SELECT
     m.mailing_name AS Mailing_Name,
    COUNT(mr.mailing_recipient_id) AS Total_Recipients
FROM mailing_recipient mr 
INNER JOIN mailing m
ON mr.mailing_id = m.mailing_id
GROUP BY m.mailing_name
ORDER BY m.mailing_name;
```

This returns the number of recipients for each email type. I am looking to create a script while returns the above in addition to the total number of email opens and the number of email opens per recipient for each email type.

The additional table is mailing_recipient_open with mailing_recipient_open_id acting as an identifier for open/clicks and mailing_recipient_open_type_id which tells whether each record acts as either an open or a click (1=click and 2=open). mailing_recipient_id acts as the foreign key between the tables.

This is the closest I have been able to get. I strongly prefer the above format because it is cleaner, but I don't know if I would be able to join as described.

```
SELECT
mailing_name,
mr.mailing_recipient_id,
mailing_recipient_open_id,
COUNT( mr.mailing_recipient_id ) AS Total_recipient,
mailing_recipient_open_id AS open_click

FROM mailing m

LEFT OUTER JOIN mailing_recipient mr ON m.mailing_id = mr.mailing_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN mailing_recipient_open mc ON mr.mailing_recipient_id = mc.mailing_recipient_id

GROUP BY mailing_name;
```

My output looks like so:

```
mailing_name    mailing_recipient_id    mailing_recipient_open_id    Total_recipient    Open_click
Mailing A       1                       NULL                         203234             NULL
Mailing B       22342                   12342                        123948             8738
Mailing C       12322                   NULL                         145203             NULL
```

And that is not right at all.

Thanks.

Comment: In any other database, this query would return an error because of the group by statement...MySQL likes to do the wrong thing and not provide an error.  Keep the count queries seperate and join them at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand what you are trying to count in your second query, but you should be able to adapt this.  The idea is to create several tables (subqueries) that have mailing_name as the key and whatever count/aggregate value you want...and join them all together on that mailing_name key

```
select a.mailing_name, a.totalrecipients, b.counter
from
(SELECT
 m.mailing_name AS Mailing_Name,
COUNT(mr.mailing_recipient_id) AS Total_Recipients
FROM mailing_recipient mr 
INNER JOIN mailing m
ON mr.mailing_id = m.mailing_id
GROUP BY m.mailing_name
)a
left join
(select mailing_name, count(*) as counter
 from tableforcounting 
group by mailing_name)b
on a.mailing_name = b.mailing_name
    ORDER BY m.mailing_name
```

YOu can continue to chain these together to get as many other counts as possible, as long as they are grouped by the same mailing_name key.  If you wanted regular fields (like mailing_name_id or the sort) join to the table on mailing name and grab the fields you want.

Hopefully that makes sense, I can clarify if you need ;)

Add:

A more generic structure of this query...

```
select a.groupingname, a.count, b.count, c.count, etc...
from
(select  groupingname, count(1) as count from table t group by  groupingname) a
left join
(select  groupingname, count(1) as count from differnt_table t where open = 1 group by  groupingname) b    
on a.groupingname = b.groupingname
left join
(select  grouping name, count(1) as count from 3rdtable t) c
on a.groupingname = c.groupingname
```

See how it's a series of subqueries, each returning a key to join on plus a count value...then the select statement simply takes the key from one table and then the rest of the count values from the subquery?

Comment: The part I do not understand is the use of a and b in the first line when m is the table for mailing name. And in terms of what I am trying to count, I am trying to determine which of three email types are the most effective by looking at the number of emails that are opened and the number of clicks within those emails (which is why there is an open_id and an open_type_id). Thanks.

Comment: A and B are the alias's of the subqueries I've used..maybe do a quick lookup on subquerying and aliases (same idea, you called a table 'm'...I'm calling a subquery 'a'.  as an example :  select a.* from (select * from table t)a     --in this, I'm selecting from table and aliasing it as t, then I'm calling that a subquery, aliasing it as 'a' and selecting a.* from it.   Hope that helps

Comment: I put a more generic version of the query...write yourself three seperate count queries that return the key of 'mailing_name' and then the count you want.  Turn these three seperate queries into subqueries, join them together, and select the counts you want from that

Comment: Thank you. I haven't quite gotten it to work, but I am getting there. It all makes a lot more sense. This is a dumb question, but do you know how I would be able to get both the open and the click to return?

Comment: Is it where mailing_recipient_open_id is not null (is populated with an id) then it is opened?  Then it's just counting by mailing_name where that field is not null :  select mailing_name, count(1) from table where mailing_recipient_open_id is not null;   I assume click to return is basically the same

Comment: I tried that. The problem is that mailing_recipient_open_id includes all of those who opened and/or clicked and mailing_recipient_open_type_id tells whether is was clicked (1) or opened (2).

Comment: select mailing_name, count(1) as click_count from table where mailing_recipient_open_type_id = 1;  that should get clicked.   select mailing_name, count(1) as open_count from table where mailing_recipient_open_type_id = 2;  and that should be opened

Comment: Thanks so much. You have been more than helpful. I really appreciate it.